# Google and Wikipedia are blocked by my country. How to research?

Tags: discussion

I am getting lots of downvotes on my question because its poorly researched (as claimed by downvoters). I want to know how to research.

I read/watched book/movie decades ago. And, I don't have access to reliable websites to do research. What to do?

Should I leave this community?

Comment: According to your profile, you are from India and [neither Google nor Wikipedia should be blocked by your country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_India). Are you asking this question as a theoretical exercise? Are you just trying to show the *unfairness* of the the General Reference/poorly researched rules?

Comment: Alternatively are you accessing the web at work? Many companies limit employee web access to sites they need for work.

Comment: [Did](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/what-was-the-purpose-of-adding-red-backlights-in-uss-enterprise#comment29669_16019) [you](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/what-keeps-hogwarts-or-hogsmade-or-azkaban-from-being-shown-in-the-google-map/10432#comment18868_10431) [change](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/in-the-last-fight-scene-of-star-trek-nemesis-how-did-shinzon-detach-his-warbir/8311#comment14376_8311) countries recently?

Comment: While I wasn't going to bring it up, @NominSim has a strong point.  You have listed India as your country in your profile.  While searching I found that the Indian government sends an average of 3 requests every 2 days to Google about blocking services or sites.  If Google were blocked, the government wouldn't be asking them to block pages or services and several searches on the topic fail to show an indication of Wikipedia being banned in India.

Comment: Have you tried reading the source material? There is no source like *the* source.

Comment: I have to ask -- when did you lose access?  You reference specific articles in the Wikipedia *and* on wikia.com in your answers.  For a lot of the material on this site, the wikis on wikia are more helpful than the Wikipedia.

Comment: @DavRob India is my home country.. I'm currently in different one

Comment: @NominSim Yes. Nice Guess.

Comment: @Keen I did have access to both. But, not at this time.

Comment: @TangoOversway Yes, I did have access to every site when I was in India.

Comment: *Which* country are you in?  Without that information, this whole discussion is pointless.

Comment: @Keen The framework is that I don't have access to reliable websites. And, I know what I am saying (I am also a web nerd). Do I really need to disclose private things?

Comment: @SachinShekhar That's not a country I've ever heard of.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Saudi Arabia seems to be the only country in the world that has blocked both Google and all of Wikipedia...

Comment: @Izkata Failed to hit my country. Anyway, Learn to value someone's privacy. I am saying its private thing and you're brainstorming around it.

Comment: @Izkata The last paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Saudi_Arabia#Internet) implies they don't block all of Wikipedia anymore.  It also links [this highly-NSFW list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_articles_censored_in_Saudi_Arabia) of articles that are blocked in Saudi Arabia, which means other articles must *not* be blocked.

Comment: @Keen Ah, I had looked over the "Censorship of Wikipedia" page [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_Wikipedia), which simply doesn't mention an end date.  Unless it meant just for one day and I misread it.

Comment: Sachin, you're telling @Keen and @ Izkata that you think that your current country's whereabouts is private? That's all well and good (I guess, I mean countries are fairly big and anyone nefarious enough to care could probably figure it out anyways), but *you asked the question* concerning the country that you are currently in having blocked content, if you don't care to tell anyone what that country is how do you expect any help at all?

Comment: @NominSim I am not seeking for answers which are dependent on country so that if I switch country again, I won't need to ask it again (which would be closed as duplicate)..

Comment: Sachin, you asked the question, about wanting to know how to research from the country that *you claim* has Google and Wikipedia blocked, but don't care to provide the name of the country, as you say that is private information. To be frank, to me this leads credence to the theory that you are simply asking this question as an excuse to justify poorly researched questions/answers. You don't seem to want to provide us with enough information to help, and seem only concerned with putting it "out there" that your "poor research" is a result of censorship that is not under your control.

Comment: @NominSim Hold on a second.. After knowing name of country, what can you really offer other than trying to negate my statements? I already know that laws are blocking websites. And, TangoOversway has already answered proxy/VPN solutions what I don't want because I don't want to break laws. That's it..

Comment: If you provided the country that you live in then we could give you a more direct and accurate answer. Additionally, from research done by others it appears that no country currently falls into the category of having blocked both Google and Wikipedia which, in addition to your apparent unwillingness to disclose that information, seems to indicate that this question was not asked in earnest IMO. We can only help you so much as you want to be helped, and asking a question regarding censorship from a new country, without disclosing what country, doesn't lead to helpful answers (again IMO).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've permanently moved to this new country that doesn't have access to Google or Wikipedia, that will severely limit the resources that you have available. However, this is the internet we are talking about, *you should be able to find other websites/search engines that will aid you in researching an answer*.

That being said, every answer has a certain layer of subjectivity, and if you feel that you aren't providing answers that have good enough references, the answer seems simple: **Don't answer them then.**

If I see for example, a Harry Potter question to which I think there is a canonical answer from the book, but don't have the reference in front of me to be accurate, **I won't answer until I do**. From your other questions <sup>[1](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/which-type-of-questions-does-sff-se-community-expect),[2](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/why-am-i-getting-too-many-downvotes-on-my-posts)</sup> you're worried about down votes, and from this one particularly about providing accurate research/sources for your answers.

Really this has to be up to you, but it seems like *you feel* that **you can't provide decent sources for answers** anymore, nor do you feel that you can **properly research a question**. If that is the case, then it is likely that your questions/answers will continue to get *some* down votes. (Keep in mind that as far as rep goes it takes only **one** up vote to counteract **five** down votes on an answer.)

According to [your comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/google-and-wikipedia-are-blocked-by-my-country-how-to-research#comment5123_2143) you say that you have are currently in a different country, could you elaborate as far as *which country* you are now in? There are plenty of resources available aside from Google or Wikipedia depending on what country you are in. [Search Engine Colossus](http://www.searchenginecolossus.com/) has a list of the best available search engines for a large collection of countries, hopefully that will provide you with sufficient resources to continue contributing quality answer/questions.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

- [The Encyclopedia of Science Fiction](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/)
- [The Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi)

?

There is more to SF&F on the web than Wikipedia and Google.

Comment: Unable to open..

Answer (score 4):

There are many proxy sites one can use, as well as VPN sites, such as StrongVPN.com, that allow one to create private connections and tunnels to other sites or to freely access the rest of the Internet.  Some proxy services are free, some have a subscription fee.

Comment: I know that. I just don't want to violate laws. Why are you ignoring the main question?

Comment: @SachinShekhar You seem to be asking two questions here. First, you ask how you can research question/answers if google/wikipedia is blocked in your country, and second you ask whether you should leave the scifi.se community. To the first, TangoOversway posted a valid answer that you are wary of due to legality concerns (check your local laws to determine this). The second is really more of a subjective, personal question that you'll need to answer.

Comment: @Xantec There can be other ways to research. I am not going to murder someone to do this..

Answer (score 3):

If the country you are currently in is blocking websites, and you don't want to use proxies to get around this I see two options that may remain legal:

Contact a friend in another country who is able to provide you with information. Or...

Head to a local library to find the local source of information.

These could both be an issue if the country has locked down these options as well, but I would certainly move before letting a country's laws force me to leave an online community such as stack exchange, though I know that is a very personal decision.